# Como abrir um exe dentro de um windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso abrir um .exe dentro de um Windows form no C#, como proceder com isso. Já pesquisei na net e achei o seguinte exemplo:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetParent")]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

Process p = Process.Start(@"d:\TesteCS.exe"); 

Thread.Sleep(500);
SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
```

o .exe abre mas fica no tamanho exato do mesmo e preciso que ele fique maximizado.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa criar uma instância de `ProcessStartInfo` e *settar* a propriedade `WindowStyle` para `Maximized`.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"d:\TesteCS.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximimized;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Então mas se coloco este código ele não apresenta o .exe dentro do meu Windows forms e sim fora da minha aplicação main.

Comment: Ah, eu não tinha lido toda a pergunta. Acho que você não vai conseguir fazer isso tão simplesmente não.